# Sorting array elements by date

Tags: ruby, arrays, sorting, date

I have the following array.

```
dates = ["6/23/2014", "8/5/2014", "8/19/2014", "6/26/2014", "8/19/2014", "8/19/2014",
"7/8/2014", "6/3/2014", "7/30/2014", "7/3/2014", "6/3/2014", "6/26/2014"]
```

Our array stores 10 string objects. In order to sort them my way, I need to re-arrange each element.

```
"2014/8/5", "2014/8/19", "2014/8/19", etc.
```

This way, 1/1/2014 doesn't come before 12/13/1994 for example.

I tried the following

```
dates.sort_by {|date|date.split(/[\/]/).rotate(-1).join('/')}
```

I would like to sort this array by date, with the newest dates first.

**Actual Output**

```
8/5/2014
8/19/2014
8/19/2014
8/19/2014
7/8/2014
7/30/2014
7/3/2014
6/3/2014
6/3/2014
6/26/2014
```

**Expected Output**

```
8/19/2014
8/19/2014
8/19/2014
8/5/2014
7/30/2014
7/3/2014
6/26/2014
6/3/2014
6/3/2014
```

The solution involves utilizing the Ruby Array Class sort_by method. I would like to sort with the date format, where newer dates come before earlier dates.

My question is, how would I sort the array based on the date.

My apologies if this is a stupid question, but I've searched this site, and couldn't find any results.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know why your expected output contains only 9 out of 12 entries, and that you mention an array of size 10, but I believe your want to sort all 12.  My preference would be to do it the way @BroiSatse has, but I will offer two ways that do not use methods from the class `Date`. I include them because it has some interesting aspects for those new to Ruby.

```
dates = [
  "6/23/2014", "8/5/2014", "8/19/2014", "6/26/2014", "8/19/2014", "10/19/2014",
  "7/8/2014", "6/3/2014", "7/30/2014", "7/3/2014", "6/3/2014", "6/26/2014"
]
```

I have changed `dates` slightly so that it includes a date having a two-digit month (`"10/19/2014"`).

**Sort by arrays of integers**

```
dates.sort_by { |d| d.split(?/).rotate(-1).map { |e| -e.to_i } }
  #=> ["10/19/2014", "8/19/2014", "8/19/2014", "8/5/2014", "7/30/2014", "7/8/2014",
  #    "7/3/2014", "6/26/2014", "6/26/2014", "6/23/2014", "6/3/2014", "6/3/2014"]
```

Here's what's happening.

```
enum = dates.sort_by
  #=> #<Enumerator: [
  #     "6/23/2014", "8/5/2014", "8/19/2014", "6/26/2014", "8/19/2014", "10/19/2014",
  #     "7/8/2014", "6/3/2014", "7/30/2014", "7/3/2014", "6/3/2014", "6/26/2014"
  #   ]:sort_by>
```

As you see, `enum` is an enumerator. The first value that it passes into its block is `"6/23/2014"`, which it assigns to the block variable:

```
d = "6/23/2014"

a = d.split(?/)
  #=> ["6", "23", "2014"]
b = a.rotate(-1)
  #=> ["2014", "6", "23"]
c = b.map { |e| -e.to_i }
  #=> [-2014, -6, -23]
```

Similarly, the third element of `enum` is converted to:

```
"8/19/2014".split(?/).rotate(-1).map { |e| -e.to_i }
  #=> [-2014, -8, -19]
```

`sort_by` uses [Array#<=>](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-3C-3D-3E) to compare pairs of elements. After reading that doc you'll understand why:

```
[-2014, -6, -23] <=> [-2014, -8, -19]
  #=> 1
```

meaning that `"8/19/2014"` should precede `"6/23/2014"` in the sort.

Incidentally, it was necessary to convert months and days from strings to integers because those strings did not contain leading zeros for single-digit values.  If we had left them as strings, `"8" > "15"`, which is not what we want. Since we are converting to integers anyway, it was easier to make them negative than to leave them positive and apply `reverse` to the sorted array.

**Sort by strings in year-month-day order padded with leading zeros as necessary, then reverse**

```
dates.sort_by do |d|
  d.sub(/(\d+)\/(\d+)\/(\d+)/) { "%4d%02d%02d" % [$3, $1, $2].map(&:to_i) }
end.reverse
  #=> ["10/19/2014", "8/19/2014", "8/19/2014", "8/5/2014", "7/30/2014", "7/8/2014",
  #    "7/3/2014", "6/26/2014", "6/26/2014", "6/23/2014", "6/3/2014", "6/3/2014"]
```

Note that

```
arr = dates.map do |d|
  d.sub(/(\d+)\/(\d+)\/(\d+)/) { "%4d%02d%02d" % [$3, $1, $2].map(&:to_i) }
end
  #=> ["20140623", "20140805", "20140819", "20140626", "20140819", "20141019",
  #    "20140708", "20140603", "20140730", "20140703", "20140603", "20140626"]
```

```
arr.sort
  #=> ["20140603", "20140603", "20140623", "20140626", "20140626", "20140703",
  #    "20140708", "20140730", "20140805", "20140819", "20140819", "20141019"]
```

See [Kernel#sprintf](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf) for formatting directives. It appears that `.map(&:to_i)` is in fact unnecessary; that Ruby treates strings representing integers as integers when the `d` directive is used.

The regular expression `/(\d+)\/(\d+)\/(\d+)/` matches one or digits (the month), which are saved to capture group 1, followed by `'/'`, followed by one or digits (the day), which are saved to capture group 2, followed by `'/'`, followed by one or digits (the year), which are saved to capture group 3. One could alternatively write this:

```
/(\d{1,2})\/(\d{1,2})\/(\d{4})/
```

or with named capture groups:

```
r = /(?<month>\d{1,2})\/(?<day>\d{1,2})\/(?<year>\d{4})/

dates.sort_by do |d|
  d.sub(r) { "%4d%02d%02d" % [$~[:year], $~[:month], $~[:day]].map(&:to_i) }
end.reverse
  #=> ["10/19/2014", "8/19/2014", "8/19/2014", "8/5/2014", "7/30/2014", "7/8/2014",
  #    "7/3/2014", "6/26/2014", "6/26/2014", "6/23/2014", "6/3/2014", "6/3/2014"]
```

`$~` is the [most recent `MatchData` object](https://ruby-doc.org/docs/ruby-doc-bundle/Manual/man-1.4/variable.html#tilde). It equals [Regexp::last_match](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Regexp.html#method-c-last_match).

Answer (score 18):

Try:

```
dates.sort_by { |s| Date.strptime(s, '%m/%d/%Y') }
```

If you want it starting from the newest date:

```
dates.sort_by { |s| Date.strptime(s, '%m/%d/%Y') }.reverse
```